# How to extract specific text from a text string when data is in another worksheet?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I have a column containing 60 Text string entries in google sheet. These are job posts.
one of the entry look like this.

```
"Procurement Manager (MEP & Civil) urgently (Construction experience is Mandatory).Company - Kleindienst experience -  Experience with 5-star hotels & luxury project will be preferred, min 10 years’ experience with same level position."
```

in another worksheet in google sheet i have a column containing more than 2000 job titles.
Say Sheet2!A1:A2000 .

I want if there is any job titles which is in another google work sheet is present in above text string then show that job title in next coulmn.

I used following formula of vlookup but failed to extract job title. sheet name in this case is Data Lookup , A2:A2000 contains all job titles in Data lookup sheet where 9 column contains same jobs titles for lookup value. C2 contains jobs descriptions as mentioned above.

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,'Data Lookup'!A2:A2000,9,FALSE)
```

but this formula is giving error. how can i get job titles.

Comment: Excel and Google sheets are different. Some formulas are compatible, but the solution for this will vary. Tag only with the software that you are actually asking about.

Comment: `'Data Lookup'!A2:I2000`. You need a lookup range with at least 9 columns.

Comment: 9th column also contains same job titles

Comment: I now used this formula =VLOOKUP(C2,'Data Lookup'!I1:J2000,2,FALSE) while i and j column contain same values. but failed

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet with your expected output. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: here is the sample sheet link  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DKKTNGPgtNpu7Av8keAd_qR6znVA3EXGPpfJCZ12Ip8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using this [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to achieve your goal.

### Sample Code:

```
/** *
* @customfunction
*/

function findmatch(text, list){

  var result = 'Not Found';
  list = list.flat();
  list.forEach( str => {
    if(text.includes(str)){
      result = str;
      return result;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

### What it does?

1. provide the `text string` in the first parameter then the list of `job titles` on the 2nd parameter
2. Change 2-d array to 1-d array using `Array.flat()`
3. Loop all job titles and check if the `text string` contains the current job title using `String.includes()`
4. Return the matched job title.

### Output:

**Formula:** `=findMatch(A2,$C$2:$C$10)`

> Note: I used `$` to lock the job title range so that it wont adjust while you drag your formula.

[image]

---

### (UPDATE)

**Here is an example if your job titles' are found on another sheet `Data Lookup`**

Formula: `=findMatch(A2,'Data Lookup'!$A$2:$A$10)`

[image]

[image]

---

**Here is an example if your job titles' are found on another Google Sheet**

> **Pre-requisite:**
>
> - Use `Importrange()` formula first to give access to the Google Sheet being imported.

Importrange Formula: `=IMPORTRANGE("Your sheet url","$A$2:$A$10")`

Formula: `=findMatch(A2,importrange("Your sheet url","$A$2:$A$10"))`

[image: Job titles on another Google Sheet]

Comment: i tried my data is in another worksheet and i used above formula but it is working only if data is on same sheet

Comment: I updated the answer with an example having the job title listed on another sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2; 'Data Lookup'!I:J; 2; 0)
```

it translates as: look for C2 in column I and if match is found return column J

Comment: not working , i have attached sample sheet in comments